# Write large data directly from mysql socket to response socket in a servlet

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, jdbc

I'm wondering if this is reasonably possible.  Say I have a (Spring) servlet that serves large files stored as blob in MySQL.  Regardless of whether that's ideal, that is the situation.

Say I serve many such requests.  I want to limit the memory used by my java application as much as possible.

It seems like, in theory, I should be able to write data as it's read from the mysql connection to the servlet response directly, without loading a big `byte[]` into my application process's memory.

I'm using Spring JDBC as well as Spring mvc, if that matters.

Thanks

Comment: File systems are better suited for large chunks of unrelational and unindexable binary data than relational database systems.

Comment: Yep, that's why I said "Regardless of whether that's ideal, that is the situation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly, that's why `ResultSet.getBinaryStream()` and `ResultSet.getCharacterStream()` exist.

Then it's just a matter of copying the contents of the `InputStream` to your `OutputStream` (presumably a `ServletOutputStream` retrieved from `HttpServletResponse` in the controller).

The amount of memory used and the actual method of transferring the data is then up to the driver. A [naive driver](http://artofsystems.blogspot.fi/2008/07/mysql-postgresql-and-blob-streaming.html) such as MySQL's will just read the whole data into a `ByteArrayInputStream`, whereas PostgreSQL for example will use its `LargeObjectAPI` to stream the data separately from the server as needed, resulting in more efficient memory usage.

Comment: I thought of this.  I wrote a very short program to check it out and ran it with a debugger.  The stream returned by getBinaryStream is actually a ByteArrayInputStream.  I looked at it with a debugger and the internal `byte[] buf` member of the BAOS had the full blob in it (704,791 bytes).

Comment: Then that's the [driver's fault](http://artofsystems.blogspot.fi/2008/07/mysql-postgresql-and-blob-streaming.html). You could try to switch to a different driver (and make sure that it handles streaming smarter).

Comment: I would think that by the time a ResultSet exists, the entire row's data has to already be in the application's memory.  Otherwise, the order in which you read different columns from the RS would matter, I'd think.

Comment: Well, don't worry. I know how this works, so you don't need to make uneducated guesses. MySQL just goes through the laziest way and fetches it all into memory. Postgres for example is a lot smarter (in many ways).

Comment: Say I had a table with two blob columns, blobA, and blobB.  If it weren't the case that the data for the whole row was in memory, then how could it be possible that *both* `rs.getBinaryStream("blobA") ; rs.getBinaryStream("blobB")` *and* the opposite order could both work?  Unless each involved another communication with the database server.  Is that the case?

Comment: Well, that goes pretty deep into the implementation. What's contained in the `ResultSet` is the `OID` of the blob, not the data (in PostgreSQL's case). The `InputStream` will then ask data from the server based on the `OID`. But this is irrelevant to your question. You should be at Google looking for a more efficient driver for your database.

Comment: It's worth a shot with the `emulateLocators`, apparently the [MariaDB driver](https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-java/) works with MySQL too.